# Reference request: destroying saturation at an inaccessible?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

An ideal $I$ on $P(\kappa)$ is said to be $\kappa^+$-saturated if there is no sequence $\langle S_\alpha \mid \alpha<\kappa^+\rangle$ of $I^+$ sets such that $\alpha<\beta<\kappa^+\implies S_\alpha\cap S_\beta\in I$.

Theorem 3.5 in Baumgartner and Taylor, *Saturation Properties of Ideals in Generic Extensions II*, gives an example of a poset that forces that there are no $\omega_2$-saturated ideals on $\omega_1$ by adding a club subset of $\omega_1$ with finite conditions.  Definition 4.2 in Cox and Eskew, *Strongly Proper Forcing and Some Problems of Foreman*, extends this to regular $\kappa=\mu^+$ with $\mu$ regular, $\mu^{<\mu}=\mu$ with a forcing $\mathbb{P}(\mu,\kappa)$.

Is there a known analogue poset for $\kappa$ inaccessible that forces there to be no $\kappa^+$-saturated ideals in the generic extension by adding a similar sort of club?

I don't believe that $\mathbb{P}(\mu,\kappa)$ as in Cox and Eskew (with choice of $\mu<\kappa$) will work, since their argument that $\mathbb{P}(\mu,\kappa)$ preserves $\kappa$ doesn't appear to go through for $\kappa>\mu^+$.

Comment: Your question appears as Question 8.5 in our paper.  It is an interesting problem, but I have no idea how to approach it.  Note that any such forcing must destroy measurability of $\kappa$, since the dual of a normal measure on $\kappa$ is a trivial example of a saturated ideal.

Comment: Not only would you have to destroy measurability of $\kappa$, but you'd have to ensure that $\kappa$'s measurability cannot be resurrected in any further $\kappa^+$-cc extension (and, more generally, that $\kappa$ does not gain a $\kappa^+$-saturated ideal in any further $\kappa^+$-cc extension).

Comment: Thanks for the info, Sean! I guess I was under the mistaken impression that there were known posets that destroyed the saturation of such ideals and the question only remained whether presaturation could simultaneously preserved.

And what prevents recovering a $\kappa^+$-saturated ideal on $\kappa$ in further $\kappa^+$-cc extensions?

Comment: My comments were confusing, you were not mistaken.  Yes, I meant that I don't know how to destroy all saturated ideals on an inaccessible in a way that also preserves presaturation.

Comment: Regarding your question about recovering saturated ideals:  this idea appeared (I think) in Kunen's paper on saturated ideals.  Suppose $\mathbb{P}$ is $\kappa^+$-cc, and $\dot{J}$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-name for a $\kappa^+$-saturated ideal on $\kappa$.  Let $I$ be the set of $A \subset \kappa$ such that $1_{\mathbb{P}}$ forces $\check{A} \in \dot{J}$.  Then $I$ is an ideal on $\kappa$ (and is normal, if $\dot{J}$ is forced to be normal).  Define a map from $P(\kappa)/I$ into $\text{ro}(\mathbb{P}) * \dot{P}(\kappa)/\dot{J}$ by sending $[S]_I$ (the $I$-equivalence class

Comment: of an $I$-positive set $S$) to the condition $([ \check{S} \notin \dot{J} ], [\check{S}]_{\dot{J}})$; here $[\check{S} \notin \dot{J}]$ denotes the $\mathbb{P}$-boolean value of that statement, and $[\check{S}]_{\dot{J}}$ is the $\mathbb{P}$-name for the $\dot{J}$-equivalence class of $\check{S}$.  This map is $\perp$-preserving, and so the $\kappa^+$-chain condition of the 2-step target poset carries down to $P(\kappa)/I$.

Comment: In short, if you can force a saturated ideal on $\kappa$ with a $\kappa^+$-cc forcing, then you already have a saturated ideal in the ground model.